# Hacking my alarm clock, how can I use it's built in display with my raspberry pi?

Tags: gpio, screen

I'm looking into hacking my digital alarm clock to be able to control it with my Raspberry Pi A+. 
It has a typical 4 digit screen (7 segment) with two dots in between.

The screen has a brand and printed on it, but no luck finding any information on this Japanese website.

The screen communicates with 14 pins, I have no other information.
How would I go about trying to power it and control it through GPIO pins ? Is it feasible?!

[Close up of connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFuF0.jpg)
[Back of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k21K.jpg)

Comment: WRT feasibility you might want to have a look at [this Q&A](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3682/5538) and [this article](https://projects.drogon.net/7-segment-led-display-for-the-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: You will need to either reverse engineer the display or find a datasheet. My guess is that you won't find datasheet so you will need to try to reverse engineer it.

Comment: I had a look at the [manufacturers page](http://www.gc-led.com.cn/products.asp?ptid=18691&leibie=0) - to save others the effort, it's in Chinese for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, this type of display has a matrix of 7 segment drives x 4 character selects, and probably another pair for the colon; there may well be an am/pm indicator. It can be common anode or common cathode.

You will need a 3V battery & a sensible resistor (320 or thereabouts) or some such to provide around 10mA to an individual LED, and try pins & note which combination lights which segments, + polarity; it soon becomes clear how it's wired. You can then play with drive currents & establish the right resistors (x7) to light it properly.

After that, it's relatively easy!

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I have been looking around online, what is all this talk of multiplexing ? I have a basic understanding of what it is / how it works, but it's still very superfluous. Your simple suggestion seems to overstep it. Do I need to understand multiplexing to get it to work?

Comment: You use the 4 lines of the matrix,  one at a time,  to select a digit;  you set the 7 lines that control the segments,  to match the selected digit.  That way you drive 28 segments with 11 pins.